# Visual Studio Code Terminal bash vs. Ubuntu for Windows 10 bash

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started with VS Code today as I have to prepare to port some of my code to Linux and I noticed that in the Terminal section there is the option of having a WSL bash, so I thought I could use this to compile my projects with gcc right there. I already installed Ubuntu for Windows 10 from the MSFT Store some time ago an installed several packages there. The thing is that the Ubuntu bash doesn't seem to share to the Linux workspace with the bash I see in VS Code, since in the latter I am lacking all those packages I already installed; it seems to be a completely different installation. Also, I noticed that the bash in the VS Code terminal uses German language while the Ubuntu App's bash is in English. (I have no idea why this is since Windows as well as VS Code is English.)

I'm quite confused about these differences, how do ubuntu.exe and bash.exe relate to each other? Can anybody shed some light on this? Obviously, it would be preferrable to to have only ONE Linux workspace in WSL so I don't have to have duplicates (of my data and also the installed packages) at different places.

Comment: what return commands `where bash` and `where ubuntu` in `cmd`? What is written in the VS Code setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"`?

Comment: `where bash` returns C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe, `where ubuntu` returns C:\Users\iko79\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApp\ubuntu.exe. Seems to support my suspiction. VS Code integrated shell references the former. Not sure why there is a Linux bash in System32 to boot, this is news to me. Any idea how to use the Ubuntu App's bash for this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use WSL bash in VS Code integrated terminal, you need to add/change setting:

```js
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
```

Restart VS Code or integrated terminal.

> If two or more WSL distro are installed, then you need to specify the path to the desired distro.

For example you can find it by running: `where ubuntu`, `where ubuntu1604` or `where ubuntu1804`. And change the settings to the desired ones. For example:

```js
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\ubuntu1604.exe",
```

Comment: That's what I have. Maybe I was not being clear: the System32 bash (which is used from VS Code) and the bash I get when I run Ubuntu for Windows 10 (e.g. from Start) are running different workspaces, apparently. This is very easily visible as an `ll` of my home directory gives me different results (even presented in different languages). My question was mostly: how can I change VS Code in a way it uses my Ubuntu bash so I don't have to re-install and copy everything to my System32 bash? Bonus question would be: why is that in the first place and how do the two bashes relate?

Comment: Okay, what's quite interesting now is this: on my Win10 machine at home it's completely different, and just as to be expected. No matter if I run the Ubuntu App or bash.exe out of System32, both show the same content. That's in fact weird and hints towards a completely unrelated issue. Here, `where ubuntu` gives me "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)." though, while on my machine at work it reports the WindowsApp folder (see my comment above).

Comment: I updated the answer. In your case, it is likely that different versions are installed on the computers you are testing, or several at once, for example ubuntu1604 and ubuntu1804. If the updated answer did not help, then you need to first indicate which WSL distro/distros you have installed. In case there are several of them, which one do you need to use in VS Code integrated terminal.

Comment: The statement of your question is not entirely correct. VS Code only runs bash or cmd in its terminal. Your problem is most likely that the wrong bash is running. In the answer, I just described how to find and specify the correct path to the desired bash. For a better understanding of the issue, it is probably worth reading this [post](https://superuser.com/a/144668/867960)

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize I can just use ubuntu.exe in VS Code like that. Works like a charm, thanks! Btw, what I did not mention: both WSL instances report the same version (16.04), so it seems as if I've got the same one installed two times -- no idea how that's possible or how it happened as I only used MSFT Store for that.

Comment: it seems there was an early version of WSL ubuntu even before the release version of Windows 10. Perhaps you were tired of this earlier version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172244/discussion-between-victor-s-and-iko79).